# Mongoose Schema with nested optional object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using the following schema:

```
{
  data1: String,
  nested: {
    nestedProp1: String,
    nestedSub: [String]
  }
}
```

When I do `new MyModel({data1: 'something}).toObject()` shows the newly created document like this:

```
{
  '_id' : 'xxxxx',
  'data1': 'something',
  'nested': {
    'nestedSub': []
  }
}
```

I.e. the nested document is created with the empty array.

How do I make "nested" to be fully optional - i.e. not created at all if it is not provided on the input data?

I **do not want to use a separate schema** for the "nested", no need of that complexity.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following schema satisfies my original requirements:

```
{
  data1: String,
  nested: {
    type: {
       nestedProp1: String,
       nestedSub: [String]
    },
    required: false
  }
}
```

With this, new docs are created with "missing" subdocument, if one is not specified.

Comment: Warning: this is not valid schema in Mongoose. It may have been when this answer was written, but it is not in current versions. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8107

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strict: false`

```
new Schema({
    'data1': String,
    'nested': {
    },
}, 
{
    strict: false
});
```

And then the schema is fully optional. To set only `nested` as fully optional maybe you can do something like:

```
new Schema({
    'data1': String,
    'nested': new Schema({}, {strict: false})
});
```

But I have never tried

Comment: Thanks, but this requires schema for the nested document.

Comment: Be aware though that setting strict to false does more than just making things optional: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Answer (score 0):

A solution without additional Schema object could use a hook like the following

```
MySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isNew && this.nested.nestedSub.length === 0) {
      this.nested.nestedSub = undefined;
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Not exactly what I hoped for - I was after a declarative schema definition.